# How to create an Angular button that redirects you to a form where one of the inputs has will get filled with text based on the button you click on?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been trying to build an app where a catalogue component has buttons that redirect me to a form component where the `textarea` will have an input based on the button that is clicked. For example: `"Hello I would like to inquire about your {{product.name}}"`

They are sibling components so I have tried doing it like this. I don't know if this is the best way to do it

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactTemplateService {

  private productSource = new BehaviorSubject('default text')
  currentProduct = this.productSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  inquiryAboutProduct(name: string) {
    this.productSource.next(name)
  }
}
```

form html

```
<body class="bg-light mt-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3 class="text-primary">How Can We Help You?</h3>
      <p class="lead mx-3">
        Message us with your questions, we'll reply as soon as possible!
      </p>
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="p-4 rounded shadow-md">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Your Name"
                formControlName="form_name"         
              />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 form-group">
              <label for="Email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
              <input
                name="email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Your Email"
                formControlName="form_email"                
              />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 form-group">
              <label for="Subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="subject"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Subject"
                formControlName="subject"               
                maxlength="50"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 mb-3 form-group">
              <label for="Message" class="form-label">Message</label>
              <textarea
                name="message"
                formControlName="message"
                cols="20"
                rows="5"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Hi, I would like to inquire about your..."
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

form component

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactUsService } from './contact-us.service';

import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import { ContactTemplateService } from './contact-template.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-us',
  templateUrl: './contact-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-us.component.css']
})
  

export class ContactUsComponent implements OnInit {
  productName!: string;
  subscription!: Subscription

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private contact: ContactTemplateService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  

  contactForm = this.fb.group({
    form_name: ['', Validators.required],
    form_email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    subject: ['', Validators.required], 
    message: ['', Validators.required],
  });


  async onSubmit() {
    emailjs.init('PApdcrgYVbBtHuMZe')
    let response = await emailjs.send('service_wpv576e', 'template_pazz7u9', {
      from_name: this.contactForm.value.form_name,
      from_email: this.contactForm.value.form_email,
      subject: this.contactForm.value.subject,
      message: this.contactForm.value.message, 
    });

    alert('Message has been sent')
    this.contactForm.reset();
  }


  inquireProducts(){
    this.subscription = this.contact.currentProduct.subscribe(productName => this.productName = productName)
  }

  

}
```

catalogue html

```
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container">
    <h2 class="display-1 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">Tech Products/
        Gadgets</h2>

    <h3 class="display-6 d-flex justify-content-center px-5 text-center">Great option for a long-term gift with a lasting
        impression. Each of these can be customised with
        company logo in the packaging or the product.</h3>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row g-5">
    
    <ng-container *ngFor="let categoryArray of Productinfo">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let product of categoryArray.Tech">
          <div
            class="d-flex justify-content-center col-xxl-3 col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-12">
            <div class="vstack gap-3">
              <div
              class="card card-cover h-100 overflow-hidden text-white bg-white rounded-5 shadow-lg"
              >
              <img src="{{ product.image }}" style="object-fit: cover" />
              <div
                class="d-flex flex-column ps-3 pe-5 fontName text-light text-shadow-1 h-100"
                style="position: absolute"
              >
                <h2 id="productName"
                  class="pt-5 mt-5 mb-4 display-6 lh-1 fw-bold"
                  style="position: relative"
                >
                  {{ product.name }}
                </h2>
                <img
                  src="../../../assets/images/bonjour-logo.png"
                  alt="Logo"
                  width="32"
                  height="32"
                  class="rounded-circle border border-dark bg-dark"
                  style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-dark" value="{{product.name}}" (click)="inquiryRedirect(product.name)" routerLink="/contact" >Inquire about {{product.name}}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      
        </div>
      </div>
```

catalogue component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactTemplateService } from 'src/app/shared-components/contact-us/contact-template.service';
import { DataStorageService } from 'src/app/shared/data-storage.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/shared/product-model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogue-tech',
  templateUrl: './catalogue-tech.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalogue-tech.component.css']
})
export class CatalogueTechComponent implements OnInit {
  Productinfo: any = []
  ProductValue!: string

  

  constructor(private service: DataStorageService, private contact: ContactTemplateService ) {}


  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.GetProductDetails().subscribe(data => {
      this.Productinfo = data;
    })
      
    

  }

  inquiryRedirect(name: string) {
    this.contact.inquiryAboutProduct(name)
      
    } 

}
```